# ImportError: cannot import name 'rmsprop' from 'keras.optimizers'

Tags: python, keras

can anybody help me. when I try to run my codes they an error
ImportError: cannot import name 'rmsprop' from 'keras.optimizers'

bellow are the libraries and all imports I used.

```
import gym
import random
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import rmsprop, Adam
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque
from statistics import mean
import h5py
```

Answer (score 32):

It should be :

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```

instead of :

```
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```

Comment: it would be lot helpful if you include the reason behind the issue and how the solution provided by you tackles it

Comment: worked for me, this happens when you find code older than keras integration

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the optimizers from Tensorflow instead of Keras library.

```
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
optimizers.RMSprop
optimizers.Adam
```

or you can directly import the required optimizer as:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop,Adam
```

and it should be **RMSprop** not **rmsprop**.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because you need to do

```
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```

As opposed to

```
from keras.optimizers import rmsprop
```

Just like variables, modules in python are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

go to keras folder in your computer and search rmsprop. Probably rmsprop is in another folder and it's not in optimizers folder.

Answer (score 0):

I tried
 `from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import RMSprop`
and it worked.